# Passing a list as variable to python script from bash script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a python script like below.

```
# Import necessary libraries and functions
import sys
import traceback

y = '2020'
querysting = "select {} from table where Year={}".format(col_list,y)
df = pd.read_sql(querystring,db)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 8:
        print('Invalid number of args......')
        print('Usage: file.py Input_path Output_path')
        exit()
    _, col_list, FinalDB, final_table, host, dsl_tbl_name, username, password = tuple(sys.argv)

    data_load(col_list, FinalDB, final_table, host, tbl_name, username, password)
```

Now I am calling this python script inside a shell script like below

```
#!/bin/bash

col_list='id, name, address, phone_number'
FinalDB='abc'
final_table='xyz'
host='xxxxxx.xxxx'
tbl_name='test'
username='USER'
password='test_pass'


python python_script.py ${col_list} ${FinalDB} ${final_table} ${host} ${tbl_name} ${username} ${password}
```

Now when I run this bash script I am getting `Invalid number of args......` error

I am pretty much sure that it is some thing to do with `col_list` variable being passed to the `python` script.

Because instead of having columns in a list if I just pass `select *` in the query and removing `col_list` variable then I don't get any errors

What am I doing wrong here and how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: You should almost always put double-quotes around variable references (e.g. `... "${col_list}" "${FinalDB}" "${final_table}" ...` instead of just `... ${col_list} ${FinalDB} ${final_table} ...`). This is a mostly-duplicate of the question: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from how you pass your variables that contains spaces from `Bash` to `Python`.

You may note that:

> In shell scripts command line arguments are separated by
>   whitespace, unless the arguments are quoted.

Let's have this simple `Python` script:

**python_script.py:**

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.arv)
```

Then in your Terminal:

```
$> export var1="hello"
$> python python_script.py $var1
['python_script.py', 'hello']
```

However:

```
$> export var1="hello, hi"
$> python python_script.py $var1
['python_script.py', 'hello,', 'hi']  # Note Here: Two args were passed
$> export var1="hello,hi"
$> python python_script.py $var1
['python_script.py', 'hello,hi']  # One arg passed
```

So, a solution to your problem, is to pass your `Bash` args as a string even with spaces, like this example:

```
$> export var1="hello, hi, hola"
$> python python_script.py "$var1"
['python_script.py', 'hello, hi, hola']
```

For more informations see this [article](https://yakking.branchable.com/posts/whitespace-safety/)